# Enabling internal routing in uWSGI

Tags: django, installation, server, uwsgi

I have a Django app working with uWSGI. My uWSGI config is:

```
[uwsgi]
http = 127.0.0.1:8000
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_django_app.settings
module = my_django_app.wsgi:application
home = /var/www/myapp/venv
chdir = /var/www/myapp/app
pidfile = /tmp/myapp.pid
logger = syslog
logfile-chown = True
logfile-chmod = 644
touch-logreopen = /var/www/uwsgi/log/rotate_monitor
uid = myapp
gid = myapp
master = True
vacuum = True
harakiri = 20
max-requests = 5000
processes = 4
threads = 1
post-buffering=4096
touch-reload = /var/www/myapp/conf/uwsgi.ini

route = ^/test log:someone called /test
```

But route directive doesn't work, I get regular uwsgi log entry. I played around it a lot, but can't find a way to make it work. Any ideas? My uWSGI version is 2.0.5.1

Comment: is internal routing enabled in your instance ? you should get a warning in startup logs if it is not available

Comment: @roberto you're completely right, I find out in log  following sign:
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had to install uWSGI with pcre support. It solved problem with routing.

To do it I had to install pcre lib(for Ubuntu the package called libpcre3) and reinstall uWSGI then. Since PCRE  is already in your system uWSGI will be automatically compiled with pcre support.

There are also points from @tobias.mcnulty comment that also might be useful:

- libpcre3-dev package on Ubuntu also needs to be installed
- afterwards you may want to run `pip install -I --no-cache-dir uwsgi` to reinstall it, otherwise you might just get the same cached wheel.
- the error in the logs is `!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!`

Comment: Note, you will also need the `libpcre3-dev` package on Ubuntu, and you will need to run `pip install -I --no-cache-dir uwsgi` to reinstall it, otherwise you might just get the same cached wheel. The error in the logs is `!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!`

Comment: @tobias.mcnulty, thank you for comment, I will add it to the answer