# uWSGI configuration to use HTTPS

Tags: linux, web-services, python-3.x, https, uwsgi

I need to have uWSGI to only allow connection through https.
I can only use uWSGI and not with extra application such as NGINX.

For now, I would be content if I can make the https part works.

I tried the code (with slight modification) from uwsgi site: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTPS.html. But it does not work.

```
[uwsgi]
master = true

socket = 127.0.0.1:9000
shared-socket = 0.0.0.0:443
https = =0,foo.crt,foo.key,HIGH

module=project.wsgi:application

enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

From the browser, I got the site cannot be reach
I have the certificate "foo.crt" and "foo.key" on the same folder as the configuration file for the code above and below. The certificate is a self sign certificate.

I also tried the following code, but only works the http and not https:

```
[uwsgi]
;master process with 5 workers.
master = true
processes = 5

http = :80
https = :443,foo.crt,foo.key

buffer-size = 32768

module=project.wsgi:application

enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

If you know how to make this HTTPS works that would awesome.
Even better, if it also includes http redirect to https.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the first glance something is wrong with your https directive. It doesn't have =0 or =1 in the beginning. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37511426/334346 . Note http-to-https directive there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this to work for https.

Like Oleg said, I miss that =0

```
[uwsgi]
;master process with 5 workers.
master = true
processes = 5

shared-socket = 0.0.0.0:443
https =  =0,foo.crt,foo.key,HIGH

module=project.wsgi:application

enable-threads = true
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```