# How can I redirect HTTPS to HTTP with uWSGI internal routing?

Tags: http, https, uwsgi

For some reasons, I need to force HTTP for my whole site.

At first, I thought that i could simply interchange key-parameters such as those shown in

1. [uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io#Force HTTPS](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Snippets.html#force-https)
2. [How can I redirect HTTP to HTTPS with uWSGI internal routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33682770/how-can-i-redirect-http-to-https-with-uwsgi-internal-routing)

leading me to do:

```
plugins = router_redirect
route-if-not = equal:${HTTP};on redirect-permanent:http://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
```

which does not work. Hence the following question: *How can I redirect* ***HTTPS*** *to* ***HTTP*** *with uWSGI internal routing?*

---

Note that the (commonly wanted) redirection from HTTP to HTTPS perfectly works within my environment, i.e., doing

```
plugins = router_redirect
route-if-not = equal:${HTTPS};on redirect-permanent:https://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you'd want this:

```
plugins = router_redirect
route-if = equal:${HTTPS};on redirect-permanent:http://${HTTP_HOST}${REQUEST_URI}
```

(...although some browsers may then change the URL back to https.)

Comment: I should have *explicitly* mentioned that I have obviously tried that. It does not work neither. This is what I meant by "I thought that i could simply interchange key-parameters such as those shown in: [...]"