# How to fix uWSGI internal routing?

Tags: django, server, installation, uwsgi

I am closely following the uWSGI tutorial on [offloading WebSockets and SSE](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/OffloadingWebsocketsAndSSE.html).
However, I have the issue that my Django worker cannot start up since uWSGI is not able to register the route. It is able to register it when I replace the socket of the SSE service with just a log call. I did make sure that the socket exists (I am using an emperor to start up both uWSGI configurations).

I found [this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624414/how-to-make-uwsgi-interal-routing-work) that suggested to enable PCRE support (which I already did). I do not get the warning about PCRE support anymore in my log file.

I am trying different possibilities for two days now and I definitely need the help of someone with a fresh mind.

This is my log when starting up the django worker (the sse worker is already started up):

```
/usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /usr/uwsgi/vassals.d/01_django.ini --die-on-term --need-app --plugin router_redirect
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/uwsgi/emperor.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/uwsgi/vassals.d/01_django.ini
unable to register route "equal:${CONTENT_TYPE};text/event-stream uwsgi:/tmp/sseapp.sock,0,0"
command terminated with exit code 1
```

this is my 01_django.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/django.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664

; wait until the sse app is loaded
wait-for-socket = /tmp/sseapp.sock

; configuring the sse app
; http-socket = :9090
offload-threads = 2
wsgi-file = /srv/okmapgo/okmapgo/wsgi.py
plugins = python

; collect X-Offload-to-SSE header and store it in var X_OFFLOAD
collect-header = X-Offload-to-SSE X_OFFLOAD
collect-header = Content-Type CONTENT_TYPE
; if X_OFFLOAD is defined, do not send the headers generated by Django
;; response-route-if-not = empty:${X_OFFLOAD} disableheaders:
; if X_OFFLOAD is defined, offload the request to the app running on /tmp/sseapp
; start the sseapp beforehand using
; uwsgi --wsgi-file /srv/okmapgo/dilcher_messaging_kafka/sseapp.py --socket /tmp/sseapp --gevent 1000 --gevent-monkey-patch
;; response-route-if-not = empty:${X_OFFLOAD} uwsgi:/tmp/sseapp,0,0
;response-route-if = equal:${CONTENT_TYPE};text/event-stream log:route triggered
response-route-if = equal:${CONTENT_TYPE};text/event-stream uwsgi:/tmp/sseapp.sock,0,0
```

The commented out "response-rout-if" entry works, the currently active one does not :-/

The referenced socket does exist (the other uwsgi socket is the socket of the emperor):

```
ls -lahrt /tmp
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Nov 15 10:55 ..
srw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          0 Nov 15 11:21 uwsgi.sock
srw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          0 Nov 15 11:21 sseapp.sock
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root        4.0K Nov 15 11:21 .
```

I am using uWSGI version 2.0.17.1. Any hints / ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: It's my blind guess but have you tried adding `router_uwsgi` plugin? Docs say that it is needed. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InternalRouting.html#uwsgi

Comment: Thanks, that most likely would have been the issue :-) However, I noticed an even easier mistake: I recompiled uwsgi with pip without removing the Alpine Linux package first - and then called the alpine version instead of the pip version. Calling the Alpine version loaded the correct plugins (including the one mentioned by you) and routing worked. Since your comment still sounds like it would solve the issue, I will accept it as an answer, if you quickly write one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to add `router_uwsgi` plugin to configuration.

[Uwsgi docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InternalRouting.html#uwsgi)